# Amazon S3 download fails: RequestTimeTooSkewed

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, fatal-error

I want to download an Amazon S3 folder, from within a bucket, via CLI. Since you cannot download sub-folders via. Console.

```sh
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.20.30 Python/3.8.5 Linux/5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 botocore/1.21.30
```

---

Update: My RequestTime is 1 hour behind ServerTime.

- **RequestTime**: `2021-08-25T20:17:12Z`
- **ServerTime**: `2021-08-26T12:13:31Z`

**How do I increase my RequestTime?**

---

I've successfully placed my access key pair into `aws configure` command.

```sh
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: <access_key_id>
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: <secret_access_key>
Default region name [None]: 
Default output format [None]:
```

I have an S3 URL, of this structure: `s3://parent_filepath/foo/bar/folder_of_interest/`

Execution with `--debug`:

```sh
danielbellio@LAPTOP-G1DAPU88:~$ aws s3 cp --recursive --debug s3://iotahoe-datascience/python_workers/dl_test/data_for_daniel/ .
2021-08-25 21:17:12,125 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/1.20.29 Python/3.8.5 Linux/5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 botocore/1.21.29
2021-08-25 21:17:12,125 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['s3', 'cp', '--recursive', '--debug', 's3://iotahoe-datascience/python_workers/dl_test/data_for_daniel/', '.']
2021-08-25 21:17:12,126 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_scalar_parsers at 0x7f1db9b1ce50>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,126 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function register_uri_param_handler at 0x7f1dba3605e0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,127 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x7f1dba2c24c0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,131 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - IMDS ENDPOINT: http://169.254.169.254/
2021-08-25 21:17:12,134 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function attach_history_handler at 0x7f1db9c57550>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,135 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.s3: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x7f1db9b259d0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,137 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.s3.anonymous: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,137 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.cp: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x7f1db9b259d0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,142 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.paths: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,142 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.dryrun: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,142 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.cp: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f1dba2ff2b0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,143 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.quiet: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,143 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.cp: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f1dba2ff2b0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,144 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.anonymous: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,144 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.acl: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,145 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.follow-symlinks: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,145 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.cp: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f1dba2ff2b0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,145 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.anonymous: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,146 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.sse: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,147 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.sse-c: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,147 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.sse-c-key: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,147 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.sse-kms-key-id: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,148 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.sse-c-copy-source: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,148 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.sse-c-copy-source-key: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,149 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.storage-class: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,149 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.grants: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,149 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.website-redirect: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,150 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.content-type: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,150 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.cache-control: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,151 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.content-disposition: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,151 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.content-encoding: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,152 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.content-language: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,152 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.expires: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,153 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.source-region: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,154 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.only-show-errors: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,154 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.cp: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f1dba2ff2b0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,155 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.anonymous: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,156 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.page-size: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,156 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.ignore-glacier-warnings: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,157 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.cp: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f1dba2ff2b0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,157 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.force-glacier-transfer: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,158 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.cp: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7f1dba2ff2b0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,159 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.request-payer: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,159 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.metadata: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,160 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.metadata-directive: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,160 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.expected-size: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,161 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.cp.anonymous: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7f1db9a7f370>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,161 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2021-08-25 21:17:12,161 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2021-08-25 21:17:12,162 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
2021-08-25 21:17:12,162 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: sso
2021-08-25 21:17:12,162 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2021-08-25 21:17:12,175 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2021-08-25 21:17:12,178 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2021-08-25 21:17:12,192 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f1dba785670>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,198 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json
2021-08-25 21:17:12,241 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7f1dba7b0ca0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,242 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f1dba7b0a60>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,246 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
2021-08-25 21:17:12,250 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/data/_retry.json
2021-08-25 21:17:12,251 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: s3
2021-08-25 21:17:12,253 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f1dba785670>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,255 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7f1dba7b0ca0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,255 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f1dba7b0a60>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,259 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
2021-08-25 21:17:12,261 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: s3
2021-08-25 21:17:12,263 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f1dba785670>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,264 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7f1dba7b0ca0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,264 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f1dba7b0a60>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,269 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
2021-08-25 21:17:12,270 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: s3
2021-08-25 21:17:12,272 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.s3.s3handler - DEBUG - Using a multipart threshold of 8388608 and a part size of 8388608
2021-08-25 21:17:12,285 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/paginators-1.json
2021-08-25 21:17:12,288 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function set_list_objects_encoding_type_url at 0x7f1dba735b80>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,288 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function validate_bucket_name at 0x7f1dba7298b0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,288 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_cache of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f1db9577640>>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,289 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method S3ArnParamHandler.handle_arn of <botocore.utils.S3ArnParamHandler object at 0x7f1db9577700>>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,289 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7f1dba729700>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,290 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function add_expect_header at 0x7f1dba729c10>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,290 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.set_request_url of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f1db9577640>>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,290 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7f1dba735f70>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,291 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=ListObjectsV2) with params: {'url_path': '/iotahoe-datascience?list-type=2', 'query_string': {'prefix': 'python_workers/dl_test/data_for_daniel/', 'encoding-type': 'url'}, 'method': 'GET', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/1.20.29 Python/3.8.5 Linux/5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 botocore/1.21.29'}, 'body': b'', 'url': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/iotahoe-datascience?list-type=2&prefix=python_workers%2Fdl_test%2Fdata_for_daniel%2F&encoding-type=url', 'context': {'client_region': 'us-east-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7f1db95bab20>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None, 'encoding_type_auto_set': True, 'signing': {'bucket': 'iotahoe-datascience'}}}
2021-08-25 21:17:12,291 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f1db95baa90>>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,292 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method ClientCreator._default_s3_presign_to_sigv2 of <botocore.client.ClientCreator object at 0x7f1db95e0d90>>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,292 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f1dba7295e0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,292 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-sign.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method S3EndpointSetter.set_endpoint of <botocore.utils.S3EndpointSetter object at 0x7f1db9577790>>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,293 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Defaulting to S3 virtual host style addressing with path style addressing fallback.
2021-08-25 21:17:12,293 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Checking for DNS compatible bucket for: https://s3.amazonaws.com/iotahoe-datascience?list-type=2&prefix=python_workers%2Fdl_test%2Fdata_for_daniel%2F&encoding-type=url
2021-08-25 21:17:12,293 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - URI updated to: https://iotahoe-datascience.s3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=python_workers%2Fdl_test%2Fdata_for_daniel%2F&encoding-type=url
2021-08-25 21:17:12,294 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2021-08-25 21:17:12,294 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
GET
/
encoding-type=url&list-type=2&prefix=python_workers%2Fdl_test%2Fdata_for_daniel%2F
host:iotahoe-datascience.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date:20210825T201712Z

host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
2021-08-25 21:17:12,294 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20210825T201712Z
20210825/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
e4f14fd5d86caf530371707ca7a13db8451306584538e8b48520e03be2d83ae0
2021-08-25 21:17:12,295 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
ff8a86a8720c3a2ae019399c78e6f6a2902d9323d462b57cc35ec06355f52163
2021-08-25 21:17:12,295 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=GET, url=https://iotahoe-datascience.s3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=python_workers%2Fdl_test%2Fdata_for_daniel%2F&encoding-type=url, headers={'User-Agent': b'aws-cli/1.20.29 Python/3.8.5 Linux/5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 botocore/1.21.29', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20210825T201712Z', 'X-Amz-Content-SHA256': b'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIARAHBOZTNVW5ZZIGU/20210825/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=ff8a86a8720c3a2ae019399c78e6f6a2902d9323d462b57cc35ec06355f52163'}>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,297 - MainThread - botocore.httpsession - DEBUG - Certificate path: /home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
2021-08-25 21:17:12,297 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): iotahoe-datascience.s3.amazonaws.com:443
2021-08-25 21:17:12,739 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://iotahoe-datascience.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /?list-type=2&prefix=python_workers%2Fdl_test%2Fdata_for_daniel%2F&encoding-type=url HTTP/1.1" 403 None
2021-08-25 21:17:12,754 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'x-amz-bucket-region': 'eu-central-1', 'x-amz-request-id': 'JQNECTZFFXWB7K1H', 'x-amz-id-2': 'SyNDbSFcc+D051KKti5p3A0hbpnrDinWH6v3XT3UUGXDr6OAt6VTxY0o+D8SRGzEDuhnBU93FYk=', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Thu, 26 Aug 2021 12:13:29 GMT', 'Server': 'AmazonS3'}
2021-08-25 21:17:12,755 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code><Message>The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.</Message><RequestTime>20210825T201712Z</RequestTime><ServerTime>2021-08-26T12:13:31Z</ServerTime><MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds>900000</MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds><RequestId>JQNECTZFFXWB7K1H</RequestId><HostId>SyNDbSFcc+D051KKti5p3A0hbpnrDinWH6v3XT3UUGXDr6OAt6VTxY0o+D8SRGzEDuhnBU93FYk=</HostId></Error>'
2021-08-25 21:17:12,763 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f1db95775e0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,763 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - No retry needed.
2021-08-25 21:17:12,764 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7f1db9577640>>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,764 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function decode_list_object_v2 at 0x7f1dba735ca0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,765 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function enhance_error_msg at 0x7f1db9b1c8b0>
2021-08-25 21:17:12,766 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.s3.results - DEBUG - Exception caught during command execution: An error occurred (RequestTimeTooSkewed) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/s3handler.py", line 173, in call
    for fileinfo in fileinfos:
  File "/home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/fileinfobuilder.py", line 31, in call
    for file_base in files:
  File "/home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/filegenerator.py", line 142, in call
    for src_path, extra_information in file_iterator:
  File "/home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/filegenerator.py", line 322, in list_objects
    for key in lister.list_objects(bucket=bucket, prefix=prefix,
  File "/home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/utils.py", line 416, in list_objects
    for page in pages:
  File "/home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 255, in __iter__
    response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
  File "/home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 332, in _make_request
    return self._method(**current_kwargs)
  File "/home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/danielbellio/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (RequestTimeTooSkewed) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
fatal error: An error occurred (RequestTimeTooSkewed) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
2021-08-25 21:17:12,771 - Thread-1 - awscli.customizations.s3.results - DEBUG - Shutdown request received in result processing thread, shutting down result thread.
```

---

I followed this [tutorial](https://devopsmyway.com/how-to-resolve-aws-s3-error-an-error-occurred-requesttimetooskewed-in-windows/) to ensure my `Windows 10` machine has Date Time automatically synced. [image]

Comment: Do you have a correct time zone set-up? Seems to me, you're sending `20210825T201712Z` which is one hour less

Comment: Ahh! My AWS IAM User account was set up in Europe (Frankfurt) eu-central-1. Might this be the issue? I'm in UK. Do I need to change my CLI to the same timezone? If so, how? @lojza

Comment: The `Z` at the end of the timestamp means that both times displayed are in UTC (the same timezone). Your calling machine seems to have incorrect time. Do you dual boot? That used to mess up windows time for me a lot.

Comment: Ah ok. No, I am just using regular `Windows 10`. @jordanm. How can I sync my system's time with aws? Rebooting my machine did nothing

Comment: what `date` command gives you?

Comment: `Thu Aug 26 15:47:53 BST 2021` @lojza

Comment: Can you update to `aws-cli/2.1.29`?

Comment: `aws-cli/2.1.29`: `bash: aws-cli/2.1.29: No such file or directory`. I've appended my current version to post. Happy to change it, if I can.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade awscli`: `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable` ... `Requirement already satisfied...`

Comment: cmd prompt: `wsl --shutdown` did not help either :(

Comment: please try with `sudo` and/or `awscliv2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New account...

---

**Solution:**

```
sudo apt install ntpdate
sudo ntpdate -sb time.nist.gov
```

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4149#issuecomment-521877012)

To confirm change:

```
curl http://s3.amazonaws.com -v
date -u
```

Both times should be the same :)

Comment: Great, it worked!
It would be helpful if you could please add a one-two liner explanation as well.